# An easy question (I think) about the subrings of $S^{-1}R$

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $S$ be a multiplicative subset of a commutative ring $R$. Now consider the homomorphism $\phi_S :S^{-1}R \mapsto R$ where $\frac{r}{s} \mapsto r$ for any $s\in S$. Now my question is:
Does this homomorphism create an inclusion preserving bijection between the subrings of $R$ and the subrings of $S^{-1}R$? I am inclined to believe that this is true but I am too tired to prove (or disprove) that. Can somebody just confirm if this is true or not (I am not looking for a solution just a yes or no answer)?

Comment: I would be *very* surprised by that. I edited out a solution (teaches me to read), but think of $\mathbb Z\subset\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 3):

In general the function $\phi_S$ isn't even well-defined, since for example
$\frac12=\frac24$.
You could try to do something with lowest terms, but that would probably not work in general and would no longer be a homomorphism. And, as Karl points out, even in the case of $\mathbb Z\subset \mathbb Q$ no such bijection exists.

Comment: For the record, the OP reversed the direction of the homomorphism in an edit for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are correct, I don't know what was I thinking with that map.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld, I changed it because I was a little confused. The first case didn't seem to work. I should look harder to find an inclusion preserving map between subrings of $R$ and $S^{-1}R$.

Comment: @user53970 First, study the given example. A bijection simply does not exist.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld, I know I edited it immediately after posting it but you were very quick.

Comment: @user53970 I know it's hard to tell across the monitor, but I have no issues with your edit; it helps to show where you are confused, if anything.